# Erros installing archlinux on macbook air

Tags: linux, grub, macbook-air, uefi

I have "installed" Archboot on my MacBook air, and I am getting screen problems after it loads UDEV, it is last thing I can read.

Basically I am following [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook). But then I got error that when installing grub legacy. Something about that it has no support of gpt. And I cannot find anything about bios-compatibility.

It only took one try too install it on macbook 6,2 and few dozens in macbook air without results.

Comment: I had used, x64, x86, cgdisk, cfdisk, parted, grub2 efi x64, grub legacy, in any possible combinations.

Comment: In the meantime, have a look at this thread on the Arch Linux forum:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=90336

Answer (score 0):

Arch Linux is for savvy super-users and mega tinkerers. It's a fine distro adn perhaps the original rolling release distro, but perhaps you would be better served by some more user amicable distro as *buntu, Mint, OpenSUSE or Fedora

Comment: Well I am using arch at least a year. This is only machine that I had problem with...

Comment: On Arch a lot of configuration is done manually, on common hardware you can go with minimal tinkering, when going with less mainstream hardware, you have a lot more work in store for you. You can try going init=/bin/bash on grub command line and try from mounting manually /sys and proc building the system manually to debug the system errors, but it is a lot of work and you'll have to do a lot of reading.